# PHP how to wait for data

Tags: php, curl, google-api, httprequest, httpresponse

Following Google documentation to create a request [(link)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request) using PHP, but received an empty response `{}` within 1 sec. I tried to use another language to send the same request, it takes about 10 secs to receive a correct response. I tried to comment out `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json` and I can get an error response of `POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header`. Wondering am I missing something in below codes?

```
<?php

$str='{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "source":{
          "imageUri":
            "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
        }
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"LOGO_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}';
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=kkkkkkeeeeeyyyyy',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json
));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

echo $resp;
?>
```

**EDIT**

If I use curl in terminal and I save the str in .json file, I can get the correct result.

Request in terminal

```
curl -v -s -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key= kkkkkkeeeeeyyyyy --data-binary @request.json
```

Request.json

```
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "source":{
          "imageUri":
            "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
        }
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"LOGO_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Response

```
*   Trying 172.217.24.202...
* Connected to vision.googleapis.com (172.217.24.202) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Users/pakhocheung/anaconda/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.googleapis.com
*  start date: Oct 24 08:38:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 29 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "vision.googleapis.com" matched cert's "*.googleapis.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v1/images:annotate?key=AIzaSyBFPRLC8BEtYPdfgg3B_aadpmKFRtfENbE HTTP/1.1
> Host: vision.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 318
> 
* upload completely sent off: 318 out of 318 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Vary: X-Origin
< Vary: Referer
< Date: Tue, 07 Nov 2017 04:13:12 GMT
< Server: ESF
< Cache-Control: private
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "logoAnnotations": [
        {
          "mid": "/m/045c7b",
          "description": "Google",
          "score": 0.34495986,
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 72,
                "y": 53
              },
              {
                "x": 400,
                "y": 53
              },
              {
                "x": 400,
                "y": 164
              },
              {
                "x": 72,
                "y": 164
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` should be a json encoded string.  It looks like you're manually entering an encoded string and then decoding it.  Something like this would be more appropriate:

```
$json='{"requests":[{"image":{"source":{"imageUri":"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"}},"features":[{"type":"LOGO_DETECTION","maxResults":1}]}]}';

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=kkkkkkeeeeeyyyyy',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json
));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

echo $resp;
```

You may want to consider defining your data in a data structure (array/object) and then using `json_encode()` to convert it to a string rather than typing your data directly into a string.  While not strictly required, I've found that it does cut down on json syntax errors.

Comment: if I use your code, I got an error of ```Invalid JSON payload received```. BTW, thanks for your advise. Cuz I want to get the correct response first, so I directly copy the string from google documentation.

Comment: My guess is that the spaces and newlines are breaking the json.  Try with the update I just made.  (I just removed all the spaces and line breaks).

Comment: Still get the same error. Please see my edit. I tried to use curl in terminal. It works. Not sure what I am missing in the conversion from curl to PHP. BTW, thanks for the help.